# How to order divs side by side and centered when get datas from database in php and css

Tags: php, html, css, division

How to order divs side by side and centered when get datas from database in php and css ?

php and html codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include ("connect.php");
    $data = $db->query("select * from videos order by id desc");
    $data ->execute();
    while ($row=$data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {?>
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="<?php echo $row['thumbnail'];?>" class="card-img" />
      <div class="card-title">
        <h3><?php echo $row['v_name'];?></h3>
        <p><a href="#"><?php echo $row['v_models'];?></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <?php }?>
  </body>
</html>
```

css style codes

```
body {
  background-color:#282828;

}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.cards{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
.card{
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: medium;
}
.card-img{
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.card-title{
  background-color: #FFFCF5;
  width: 240px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #282828;
}
.card-title>p>a{
  color: #00BFA5;
}
```

my page looks like this:
[image]

but I want to those pictures order side by side

I couldn't that. How could I do? 
Thank you

Comment: remove `$data ->execute();` you don't need it `query()` is just fine

Comment: thanks but it didn't change anything

Comment: I know it was not gonna change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got `.cards` inside you while loop, take it out:

```
  <body>
  <div class="cards">
    <?php include ("connect.php");
    $data = $db->query("select * from videos order by id desc");
    $data ->execute();
    while ($row=$data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {?>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="<?php echo $row['thumbnail'];?>" class="card-img" />
      <div class="card-title">
        <h3><?php echo $row['v_name'];?></h3>
        <p><a href="#"><?php echo $row['v_models'];?></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
  </div>
  </body>
```

The reason your code doesnt work, is because `.card` is inline-block which will place multiple `card` nexto eachother, but because you look the `.cards` (note the S) as well, you wrap each item in a div. A div is a block element, which means it'll take up one whole row, the next element will fall below it.

Answer (score 1):

For each row from database you parse, you will have this following output:

`

```
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="<?php echo $row['thumbnail'];?>" class="card-img" />
      <div class="card-title">
        <h3><?php echo $row['v_name'];?></h3>
        <p><a href="#"><?php echo $row['v_models'];?></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`

So, all you have to do is to have the cotainer outside the while loop, like this:

`

```
<div class="cards">
<?php include ("connect.php");
    $data = $db->query("select * from videos order by id desc");
    $data ->execute();
    while ($row=$data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {?>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="<?php echo $row['thumbnail'];?>" class="card-img" />
      <div class="card-title">
        <h3><?php echo $row['v_name'];?></h3>
        <p><a href="#"><?php echo $row['v_models'];?></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php }?>
  </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you want, but try :

```
cards { display : flex ; flex-direction : row ; justify-content : space-between }
```

/ ! \ Doesn't work on IE8 and previous